# Should I have separate sitemaps for each brand/client under the same domain?

Tags: seo, sitemap, branding

I have a multi-client website, each brand/client name is under the same domain, for example: `example.com/nike`, `example.com/addidas`, and so on...

Should I have a separate sitemap for each brand/client for SEO?

Comment: It's unclear how many pages you have under each brand/client, and whether you're trying to have those indexed as part of the domain or separately, but in general you don't need a sitemap at all. Google will find and crawl each page, and index them according the content found on that page.

Comment: Do you need to report stats about how much of each brand is indexed to your your clients?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller yes how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you want to have one sitemap for a domain or subdomain. (Though most sitemap generators will now break up the single sitemap file into multiple files for pages, posts, etc.)

In your case, each client has a subdirectory, not a subdomain. So a sitemap for all of these subdirectories, even if they have child pages, would most likely be overkill.

As Dan mentioned above, sitemaps have generally been depreciated in importance; some may argue otherwise, but modern search engines will indeed find all of your content just fine if you don't noindex or gate something on the way to deeper indexable content.

Sitemaps are now mostly suggestions to search engines about what the most important or most recently updated pages are. They're increasingly nice-to-haves, so don't burden yourself with maintaining multiple sitemaps for a single domain.

Here's a great article on the subject. Sums it up quite well:

https://robertmohns.com/writing/do-sites-really-need-a-sitemapxml-for-good-seo